# In MAUI, how to adjust an image of a button to the size of the button?

Tags: maui

I am trying to add an image to a button. I am using this code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Para el menú, como por ejemplo settings.-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Button HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Command="{Binding ResgistrarEntradaCommand}"
            ImageSource="entrada.svg"/>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding ResgistrarSalidaCommand}"
            ImageSource="salida.svg" />
</Grid>
```

If I don't set the image, the second button has the desired size, relative to the row of the grid. However, if I set the image, that is much bigger than the screen, the button adjust its size to the size of the image.

Is there some way to make the image adjust the size to the size of the button and keep the relation beetween the height and the width?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot control this, to change this you need to change the image itself,

Comment: I have seen that there is an ImageButton, but I have another problem with that control, that perhaps it is better to ask in another question, to don't mix.

Comment: I am actually working on a control that handles the situation that you are in right now in my custom control library for Maui, once i am done if you want i can link it here

Comment: Thanks so much, it you be great if you could share the solution.